# What is a good introduction to asian (korean) philosphy?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

The title says it all. I looking into studying abroad in South Korea (I'm from Germany) in a year or so and I want to have at least a working knowledge of the philosophical workings of Asia and specifically of Korean philosophy. What would be a good starting point to familiarize myself with these philosophical viewpoints.

Comment: I added an answer, but since the field is broad was there any _specific_ school or period you had in mind?

Answer (score 4):

Korean philosophy is very broad field and has been influenced by Buddhism and Noe-Confuciasm over the years, but I suspect as [Wikipedia cites in the reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_philosophy#References) *A Modern History of Korean Philosophy* will give you a holistic picture.

I recommend the book *Don't-Know Mind: The Spirit of Korean Zen* ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590301102)) parts of which I found thoroughly enlightening and searching related books in the aforecited ink will give you other options.

Hope it helped.